# Unable to add Fragment to the Navigation Drawer

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-recyclerview, navigation-drawer, drawerlayout

I am trying to add a Fragment inside the Navigation Drawer but strangely the final output does not seems like a navigation drawer. In the image below The Drawer is static on the page with no Frame layout content and toolbar. My Doubt is whether can we add the RecyclerView inside Fragment and then display it or should I just use the RecyclerView?

[image]

Following are the files:

MainActivity.java:

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    setupToolbar();
    drawerLayout = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawerMainActivity);
    setupDrawerToggle();
    Fragment squadFragment = new SquadFragment();
    FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction =  getFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
    fragmentTransaction.replace(R.id.containerView,squadFragment,null);
    fragmentTransaction.commit();

}

void setupToolbar(){
    toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolBar);
    setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
    getSupportActionBar().setDisplayShowHomeEnabled(true);
}

void setupDrawerToggle(){
    drawerToggle = new  ActionBarDrawerToggle(this,drawerLayout,toolbar,R.string.app_name,R.string.app_n   ame);
    //This is necessary to change the icon of the Drawer Toggle upon state  change.
    drawerToggle.syncState();
}
```

}

ReyclerViewFragment.java :

```
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,  Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    View v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.recyclerfragment,container,false);


    navTitles = getResources().getStringArray(R.array.navDrawerItems);
    navIcons = getResources().obtainTypedArray(R.array.navDrawerIcons);
    recyclerViewAdapter = new  Adapter(navTitles,navIcons,getActivity().getApplicationContext());
   recyclerView = (RecyclerView) v.findViewById(R.id.recyclerView);
    recyclerView.setAdapter(new  Adapter(null,null,getActivity().getApplicationContext()));
    recyclerView.setLayoutManager(new  LinearLayoutManager(getActivity().getApplicationContext()));
    recyclerView.setAdapter(recyclerViewAdapter);

    return v;
}
```

activity_main.xml :

```
 <android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout   xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
 xmlns:local="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
 android:id="@+id/drawerMainActivity"
 android:layout_width="match_parent"
 android:layout_height="match_parent">

 <LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">
    <include android:id="@+id/toolBar"
        layout="@layout/app_bar"/>
    <FrameLayout
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:id="@+id/containerView">


    </FrameLayout>
</LinearLayout>

<fragment
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:name="com.example.hp.recyclernavigation.RecyclerFragment"
    android:id="@+id/fragment"
    >

    </fragment>

</android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout>
```

recyclerfragment.xml:

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:layout_height="match_parent" >

<android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:id="@+id/recyclerView"
    android:background="#FFFFFF"
    android:layout_gravity="start"
    />
</LinearLayout>
```

Adapter.java:

```
 Adapter(String[] titles , TypedArray icons , Context context){

    this.titles = titles;
    this.icons = icons;
    this.context = context;
 //        inflator=LayoutInflater.from(context);
 }

public class ViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder  {

    TextView  navTitle;
    ImageView navIcon;
    Context context;

    public ViewHolder(View drawerItem , int itemType , Context context){

        super(drawerItem);
        this.context = context;
      //  drawerItem.setOnClickListener(this);
        if(itemType==1){
            navTitle = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.tv_NavTitle);
            navIcon = (ImageView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.iv_NavIcon);
        }
    }
}

 @Override
 public Adapter.ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType)    {

    LayoutInflater layoutInflater = (LayoutInflater)  parent.getContext().getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);

    if(viewType==1){
        View itemLayout =    layoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.drawer_item_layout,null);
        return new ViewHolder(itemLayout,viewType,context);
    }
    else if (viewType==0) {
        View itemHeader =   layoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.header_layout,null);
        return new ViewHolder(itemHeader,viewType,context);
    }
    return null;
}
@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(Adapter.ViewHolder holder, int position) {

    if(position!=0){
        holder.navTitle.setText(titles[position - 1]);
        holder.navIcon.setImageResource(icons.getResourceId(position-1,-1));
    }
}
@Override
public int getItemCount() {
    return titles.length+1;
}
@Override
public int getItemViewType(int position) {
    if(position==0)return 0;
    else return 1;
}
```

Can Someone Please help me!!

Comment: Android introduced `NavigationView` almost an year ago in Design library that takes care of setting up the Drawer. Consider using that instead  http://android-developers.blogspot.se/2015/05/android-design-support-library.html

Answer (score 1):

You can view Android Navigation Drawer Sample by Google:
https://github.com/googlesamples/android-NavigationDrawer

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you have failed to specify the layout_gravity as well as the width property for the DrawerLayout

Your Layout should look somewhat like this

```
<android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout
    android:id="@+id/drawer"
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <FrameLayout
        android:id="@+id/container"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:clickable="true"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"/>

    <fragment
        android:id="@+id/fragment_drawer"
        android:name="wsl.com.dryv.fragment.MainNavigationDrawerFragment"
        android:layout_width="@dimen/navigation_drawer_width"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_gravity="start"
        app:layout="@layout/fragment_navigation_drawer"/>
</android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout>
```

Comment: I am having recyclerview inside the fragment and this fragment I am adding inside the drawer layout..to which values will the "dimen/navigation_drawer_width" and the "layout/fragment_navigation_drawer" point to? Will they refer to the width and layout of recyclerview?

Comment: The width is totally dependent on you. I would however recommend something between 200dp-250dp. The layout should refer to the layout of your main fragment. Which should be @layout/recyclerfragment.